# Does Stack Overflow stop using system-wide push notifications on old questions?

Tags: discussion, notifications

I noticed when somebody makes an edit or posts an answer to an older question, the push notification does not come up.

I can understand this rationale because newly, unanswered posts tend to get a lot of attention compared to older, already answered questions.

Have you experienced this as well? How old does a question have to be before push notifications stop going out?

Comment: Can't reproduce on question from October 2010 so it's not related to being old. Can you link to specific question you don't get notification for?

Comment: By "push notification", are you talking about the live refresh stuff that appears on the page? Or are you talking about notifications that appear in your inbox?